# Linearly independent subset under linear 1-to-1 transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear and one-to-one. Let $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k\}$ be a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Prove that the set $\left\{T(v_1), T(v_2), \ldots, T(v_k)\right\}$ is a linearly 
independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I don't even understand what this is asking me to do.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: What is a linearly independent set? What is a linear function? What is a one-to-one function? Given these, you understand what $\mathcal{V} = \{v_i\}_{i=1}^k$ and $T$ are. Can you show that $T(\mathcal{V})$ is still linearly independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is asking you to write up and verify the definition of '*linearly independent*', by knowing what '*one-to-one*' and '*linear map*' means.

> $\sum_i(\lambda_i\cdot Tv_i)\,=0\ \implies\ T\left(\sum_i \lambda_iv_i\right)=0\ \implies\ \left(\sum_i \lambda_iv_i\right)=0\ \implies\ \forall i:\lambda_i=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right" (by myself, not in a class).  I just wrote up a proof of this exact problem.  Would you (the Math Stack Exchange community) look over my proof to see if it is correct?

*Let T be a linear map from V to W and let T be 1-1.  Suppose that $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is linearly independent in V.  Prove that $(Tv_1,...,Tv_n)$ is linearly independent in W.*

**Proof:**

Let $a_1v_1 + ...+ a_nv_n$ be an arbitrary vector in V, such that not all $a_i$'s are zero.
Then $T(a_1v_1 + ...+ a_nv_n$) = $Ta_1v_1 + ... + Ta_nv_n = a_1Tv_n + ... + a_nTv_n$ because of the properties of a linear map.
Suppose that  $a_1Tv_n + ... + a_nTv_n$ = $b_1Tv_n + ... + b_nTv_n$.
Because T is 1-1, $a_1v_1 + ...+ a_nv_n$ = $b_1v_1 + ...+ b_nv_n$.
Then, $(a_1 - b_1)v_1 + ... + (a_n - b_n)v_n = 0$.
Since $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is linearly independent in V, then $(a_1 - b_1) = 0$, or $a_1 = b_1$; ... ; $(a_n - b_n) = 0$, or $a_n = b_n$.
Thus, $(a_1 - b_1)Tv_1 + ... + (a_n - b_n)Tv_n = 0$ with $a_i - b_i = 0$, which shows that $(Tv_1,...,Tv_n)$ is linearly independent in W.